# Ordering in process pool python

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to return the result from processes running in parallel in python. Here is the code .

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from itertools import *
import time
import random

def abcd(a):
    time.sleep(a)
    print(a)
    return a

p = Pool(3)
a = p.starmap(abcd, zip([10, 2, 15]))
p.close()
p.join()
print(a)
```

Is the result always returned  in the order of the array inside zip ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Pool.starmap` (and `Pool.map`) will return the values in order of the arguments passed into them -- this does not however mean that they will be run in order.  If you don't care about order and are ok with *unordered* results (and potentially more performance) there is `Pool.imap_unordered`.

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap)

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that they will be in the same order because ultimately the OS handles scheduling the processes. They may end up in the same order, and you might be able to increase the chances of it if you set `chunksize` to 1 in `starmap()`. Otherwise, at best the results will be in execution order grouped by chunk size.

If you need to know the original order afterwards, the trick I use is to just pass in an index (or a `numpy.ndindex` for n-dimensional data) that is just re-emitted by the worker function.